# Creating Epub on the basis of Template

Tags: epub

I have been working on creating Epub for my work. I have used Aspose to create the Epub. In this process numerous word document is merged together and single epub file is created. Now I am asked to create an EPub based on  a template. I have been searching a way to do it but I am no where near to the solution. I haven't even found the template for Epub which will render smoothly over various devices IOS and android. Similarly I have no clue how I will achieve this task programmatically. If anyone out there have any idea please provide me an insight.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know an ePub is a file that contains a lot of html pages. if you want to create a template based epub programmatically you should link this files to a css and modify the structure of the html as the template.
If I were you I would use a regex to edit the html files, get the contents and place this contents in a new html page. Once done that I would place the html page in the epub.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you please create the template document (DOTX) using MS Word. Import this template document into Aspose.Words' DOM, merge Word documents, do other document processing tasks, and save it to EPUB using Document.Save method. You may also create the template document programmatically using Aspose.Words. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.